# sort the array and remove part of it afterwards

Tags: php, sorting

I have a 2d array called `$myarray` and I use `var_dump($myarray)`, it gives me the following:

```
 array(4) { 
    [0]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(11) "PAY000003RV" 
        [1]=> string(3) "EUR" 
        [2] => string(9) "43,543.23"  
    } 
    [1]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(11) "PAY000002PE" 
        [1]=> string  (3) "USD" 
        [2]=> string(9) "13,432.34" 
    } [2]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(11) "PAY000001YB" 
        [1] => string(3) "GBP" 
        [2]=> string(8) "3,432.21" 
    } [3]=> array(3) { 
        [0]=> string(11) "PAY000004TS" 
        [1]=> string(3) "CAD" 
        [2]=> string(8) "2,321.34" 
    } 
}
```

I want to get the following output:

```
 GBP 3,432.21
 USD 13,432.34
 EUR 43,543.23
 CAD 2,321.34
```

so I try to use `substr($myarray[0][0], 8, 1)`,  `substr($myarray[1][0], 8, 1)`,   `substr($myarray[2][0], 8, 1)`,    `substr($myarray[3][0], 8, 1)` to get the value 3,2,1,4 in order to use it to sort the array to the above order and then delete `$myarray[0][0]`, `$myarray[1][0]`, `$myarray[2][0]`, `$myarray[3][0]` which are the "PAY0000.." elements in every row, but I am not sure how exactly to implement that, any experts could help me with that? any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
//Extract sort key
$tmp=array();
foreach($myarray as $m) $tmp[$m[0]]=array($m[1],$m[2]);

//Sort array
ksort($tmp);

//Create output
foreach($tmp as $m) echo $m[0].' '.$m[1];
```

Some comments:

- You can sort by `PAY00000nXY` without extracting n
- The code assumes you need the array for more than printing it out, else it might be inefficient

Comment: thank you, can you tell me what is $m[0] mean in $tmp[$m[0]], is it mean: $tmp[0], $tmp[1], $tmp[2], $tmp[3]?

Comment: In this line we walk the original array in $m, so $m[0]=$tmp[0][0],$tmp[1][0],$tmp[2][0] ... it is `PAY00000nXY` . We use this as a new key in $tmp, so `$tmp[$m[0]]=array($m[1],$m[2]);`means "create a new key `PAY00000nXY` in $tmp and asign to it an arry consisting of the currency and value"

Comment: thank you, brilliant, but how can you sort the key PAY00000nXY without using substring, how can you compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say your array is assigned to variable `$foo`

```
$values = array();

foreach ( $foo as $bar ) {  
    foreach ( $bar as $val ) {  
        $values[] = $val[1] . ' ' . $val[2];
    }  
}
```

Then you will have the array `$values` with the values you need.